# Testflight question on teammate's devices were not identified?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, testflight

From TestFlight I get this on the build and distribution:  "These teammate's devices were not identified in the embedded.mobileprovision for this build."

What do I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will have to re-create the mobile profile with these devices added to it.  Then, you'll need to re-build your iOS application and be sure that it is created with this new provisioning profile.  Only then will these other users have access to the application (and then their devices will show up in TestFlight for that build's allowed devices).

Comment: In the Apple Provisioning Portal for your iTunes developer account.

Comment: Test Flight gave me: deviceIdentifier deviceName;  but the Apple Provisioning Portal asks for: Profile Name, cert, App Id, and Device ?

Comment: If your existing profile is setup, you simply need to add devices to it. That only requires the device UDID and a name you specify.  This would be a good read: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html

Comment: @dtuckernet, The link you provide is broken. Can you tell me the name of the title? Thanks.